# What is a phrase for a person who changes their story to satisfy whoever they're addressing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests, politics, gender-positive

What is a phrase to describe a person (especially a woman) running for office who tells different political factions what they want to hear in order to win their vote?

Comment: There are a bunch of words that are gender-neutral, like _two-faced_ and _chameleon_; must this be specifically to describe a woman? And what about the connotation? Adding a sample sentence would be useful, too.

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Comment: "A politician."

Comment: *electoralist* or *demagogue* apply to both genders.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person might be said to **[pander](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pander-to#:%7E:text=%2F%CB%88p%C3%A6n.d%C9%9A%2F,panders%20to%20his%20every%20whim.)** to the various factions involved, or to emulate **[The Vicar of Bray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vicar_of_Bray_(song))**, although the latter is more about retaining a position rather than obtaining one.

Comment: "Buttering their bread" is a saying that comes to mind.